# Chrome Extension - Communicating with external program

Tags: javascript, python, html, google-chrome

I have an external application that is automating some tasks on a website. My goal is to implement a system which allows for the program and Chrome to synchronize cookies. While it is possible to query Chrome's cookie DB to read cookies, it is not possible to update the DB since Chrome maintains an I/O lock on the file, thus preventing easy synchronization.

The next logical step to me was to attempt to create an extension which will update cookies as necessary (through Chrome's cookie API). However, after about two days of research I have been unable to find an effective means to communicating cookie data between the browser and my application (which is written in Python.)

Sockets are out because it's for desktop based applications only. Websockets are out because as far as I can see it's impossible to setup a Websocket server using the HTML5 API (which is what I need since the browser needs to be the server and the program would be a connecting client). I'm really not sure what I am left with at this point. Is there something really obvious that I'm missing here? Any help is appreciated, cheers.

Comment: Why can't you use sockets? Also, why does the browser need to be the server? Some extra info would be helpful :)

Comment: "desktop based applications only". "some tasks on a website". What?

Comment: I was told that I could not use sockets in an extension. In fact, when I tried to load sockets into my extension, I received the "Invalid value for permissions[2]" using this meta file: http://pastebin.com/Exj3feFP. It only makes sense for the browser to be the server because there's only one browser and possibly multiple instances of my program being open. Having the browser as the server will allow for all application instances to connect to the browser rather than the browser trying to find and connect to each application instance. Does this help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feels like a very weird way to do whatever you're trying to do. Why are you doing this again?

Anyway, the most obvious solution is this:

[image]

You obviously have to secure communication between the app/plugin and the server. Again, this feels like a very weird way of doing stuff. But the solution will work. In this case *both* the app and the plugin are WS clients and your server is the arbiter.

Comment: I'll give this a shot. I'm attempting to synchronize cookies between Google Chrome and a Python application. Unless there's some other way that I'm just not seeing, this sort of implementation is my only real option.

Comment: Editing files is out of the question (as you realized) and I'm not aware of any MPI-style JS library, so web-sockets (or AJAX) may be your best bet. Just make sure you synchronize the correct browsers.